# Is it normal to experience headache while quitting smoking

Tags: pain, eye, treatment, smoking, headache

I wanted to quit smoking, (this is the third attempt to do that), I am a 11 years heavy smoker.

In the first 4 days, i would smoke just 4 cigarettes a day.

Then, I decided to cut cold turkey.

Now, it has been around 12 hours since the last cigarette i took but my head is hurting, i feel headache above the left eye.

Is that normal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is normal, since Nicotine is a drug which not only affect many parts of your body‚ but it also affect your brain. Withdrawal feelings usually are the strongest in the first few weeks after quitting and many people start smoking again to feel better. See: [Understanding Nicotine Withdrawal](https://smokefree.gov/withdrawal).

During the quitting process the following physical symptoms may occur:

- Tingling in the hands and feet
- Sweating
- Intestinal disorders (cramps, nausea)
- Headache
- Cold symptoms as the lungs begin to clear (sore throats, coughing, and other signs of colds and respiratory problem).

This also includes mental and emotional symptoms such as:

- Feelings of being an infant: temper tantrums, intense needs, feelings of dependency, a state of near paralysis.
- Insomnia
- Mental confusion
- Vagueness
- Irritability
- Anxiety
- Depression

<sup>Source: [Nicotine Withdrawal Symptoms & Recovery](http://www.quitsmokingsupport.com/withdrawal1.htm) at QuitSmokingSupport.com</sup>

See also: [What happens when you quit?](https://www.nhs.uk/smokefree/why-quit/what-happens-when-you-quit) at NHS